# PowerBI DAX for Finding Last Record

Tags: powerbi, dax

**Question**

What is an efficient way to create a calculated column finding the last value of my `DATE` column, using the `ModifiedOn` column, per `ID`? I don't want the MAX date, just the last record (even if the last record is the minimum). Also, my table is a calculated column.

**Example Table**

ID
DATE
ModifiedOn

A
2/4/2020
1/16/2019

A
2/5/2020
1/17/2019

B
3/2/2020
2/7/2020

B
3/3/2020
2/8/2020

B
3/1/2020
2/9/2020

**Current Formula**

```
LastRecord = 
VAR Max_Date =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( 'Table1'[ModifiedOn] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table1', 'Table1'[ID] )
 )

RETURN
IF (
    Table1[ModifiedOn] = Max_Date,
    Table1[DATE]
    )
```

**Current Results**

But using the formula I get a calculated column that looks like this:
I keep getting blanks where they should be filled with the LAST recorded date of that ID.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following dax formula to create the expected column:

```
Column = 
VAR __id = 'Table'[ID]
VAR __lastMod = 
    CALCULATE( 
        MAX( 'Table'[ModifiedOn] ),
        FILTER( 'Table', 'Table'[ID] = __id )
    )

VAR __lastDate =
    CALCULATE(
        MAX( 'Table'[Date] ),
        FILTER( 'Table', 'Table'[ID] = __id && 'Table'[ModifiedOn] = __lastMod )
    )

Return __lastDate
```